# get vector which's mean is zero from arbitrary vector

Tags: matlab, numerical-computing

as  i know  to get  zero mean vector from given vector,we should substract  mean  of given vector from each memeber  of this  vector.for example let us   see following example

```
r=rand(1,6)
```

we get

```
0.8687    0.0844    0.3998    0.2599    0.8001    0.4314
```

let us create another vector  s by following operation

```
s=r-mean(r(:));
```

after this we get

```
 0.3947   -0.3896   -0.0743   -0.2142    0.3260   -0.0426
```

if we calculate  mean of s by following formula

```
  mean(s)
```

we get
                ans =

```
 -5.5511e-017
```

actually as i  have checked this number is very small

```
     -5.5511*exp(-017)

ans =

 -2.2981e-007
```

so  we should think that our vector has mean zero?so it means that  that small deviation from 0 is because of round off error?for exmaple when we are creating white noise or  such kind off random uncorrelated   sequence of data,actually it is already  supposed that even  for such  small  data   far from 0,it has  zero  mean and it is  supposed in this case that  for example for this case

```
  -5.5511e-017 =0 ?
```

approximately of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e-017 means 10 to the power of -17 (10^-17) but still the number is very small and hypothetically it is 0. And if you type

```
format long;
```

you will see the real precision used by Matlab

Comment: actually that just outputs to 16 digits precission. The real precission depends on the datatype (usually double) used by matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can refer to the eps command. Although matlab uses double that can encode numbers down to `2.2251e-308` the precission is determined size of the number.

Use it in the format `eps(number)` - it tell you the how large is the influence of the least significant bit.

on my machine eg. `eps(0.3)` returns `5.5511e-17` - exactly the number you report.